# How can I autoresize views according to available space (after rotation) in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen-rotation

I need to create a layout where 3 views are stacked vertically and the second one must stay centered both vertically and horizontally.
What is happening is that when I turn the phone in Landscape, the first view overlapse the second one. I just want it to resize automatically in order to keep the stacked layout.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the mechanism Size Classes, and set the constraints suitable for vertical orientation of the screen as well as for horizontal. Here is a good guide: [tutorial](https://bradbambara.wordpress.com/2015/11/30/size-class-concepts-in-ios/)